# Handling time consuming operations using Nodejs and AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

The current setup of the project I am working on is based on Nodejs/Express and AWS. AWS Lambda is triggered on a daily basis and is used to call an API endpoint which is expected to fire a varying number of emails via Sendgrid (hundreds to thousands). With a lower number of emails it worked fine but when the number of emails was around 1000 the Lambda timed out and the API crashed.

The limit on Lambda was 1 minute. Raising it up to 5 minutes might make this case of 1000 emails pass but might fail when the number is several thousands. Apart from that we would like to avoid keeping the server busy for several minutes because of which it was set to 1 minute initially.

We are now looking for better solutions to this specific situation. What would be a better approach, is it an option to use SNS Queue, or Serverless with moving all the code that sends the emails to Lambda?

Thanks for any inputs in advance and if more information is required please let me know.

Comment: is the lambda given a maximum timeout as 5 minutes, does it exceeds 5 minutes?

Comment: If you require more execution time than what currently maxes out at, ie 5 mins, you could use the lambda to trigger an aws fargate container that sends out the emails. 

Aws fargate uses a docker container provided by you to do so

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about your current solution? Where are the email addresses stored? Is the API endpoint Sendgrids? If so, is it rate limited? Does the Lambda make 1 api call or a 1000?

Comment: Look up https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/

Comment: @GowthamChand the limit was set to 60 seconds initially with the goal of keeping the time that the server is busy lower. Raising it up to 5 minutes might work for this "1000 emails" case but might hit the limit when several thousands would be fired. Apart from that we would like to avoid keeping it busy even for 2-3 minutes. I updated the question as well with these information.

Comment: @SwarajGiri thanks, will take a look into fargate.

Comment: @KMo Sure, the email addresses are stored in the DB. Lambda makes 1 call to the REST API which calls Sendgrid endpoints for email sending. There is not a limit on Sendgrid for this number of emailsa as far as I know but I will check that as well. Thanks all!

Comment: Looking at Sendgrid's documentation (API V3) you can make upto 10000 api calls a second, but only include upto 1000 recipients in one call. So anything over 1000 email addresses in one API call will fail anyway. What language are you using in your Lambda?  Could you chunk your list of addresses up and make several synchronous calls to the Sendbird API?

Comment: @KMo Correct. It is already 1 call per recipient since the email content varies from other data. Nodejs on Lambda side as well. Chunking or cueing is I believe the way to go, but not sure how to do it best. Even if we would chunk the calls from Lambda (meaning doing more calls) we would still have the (more or less) same time consumption and server being busy during execution. Is it an option to move the code that triggers the emails on AWS instead of being part of the API/server?

Comment: @nera So you have your API end point and server sitting between the Lambda and Sendbird's API?

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are not designed for long running operations. You can use Elastic Beanstalk Workers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Briefly, the lambda publish the task to an SQS queue and an elastic beanstalk app handles it.